# Why is letter L used to indicate wide chars strings?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
wchar_t* str = L"hello";
```

Why "L" and no other letter?

Comment: **L** is an abbreviation of **Wide**, obviously.

Comment: @Keeper Perhaps it is that I am not an native English speaker, and  that's why I don´t see the relationship. As dan04 says, a letter U makes more sense.

Comment: @Kiewic: He is being sarcastic (implying that the choice of L is not intuitive).

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because the `L` suffix is used on integer constants. It appears to be a case of reuse of an existing suffix as a prefix. The other answer is that this is committee-designed. Don't ask. The third answer is what letter or other mechanism would you have chosen, and can you justify it against the `L` convention? Argue both for and against.

Worse than reuse of `L` is reuse of keywords like `static` and `auto` with new meanings. :)

By the way, this is touched upon in the Rationale for ANSI C (from back in 1989). They don't explain why L was chosen. There is just this:

> *An L prefix distinguishes wide string literals.  A prefix (as opposed to suffix) notation was adopted so that a translator can know at the start of the processing of a long string literal whether it is dealing with ordinary or wide characters.  (See §2.2.1.2.)*

Section 2.2.1.2 provides no additional clues.

Comment: I guess the letter `W` would have been an obvious choice too.

Comment: At least C++11 made the sensible choice of `U` for Unicode strings.

Comment: @dan04: The use of `U` for Unicode is not new in C++11, we already had `\U` for single Unicode characters.

Answer (score 5):

MSDN claim it stands for string **Literal**, ie the entered string should not be translated into anything else

Comment: Doesn't really make much sense either... seeing how _"abc"_ is a string literal, too; just `char` instead of `wchar_t`

Comment: MSDN-based answer about standard C++ gets four votes? That is messed up, LOL.